# sql server order by alpha then numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, alphanumeric

I have issue with sort order, the result is listing 0 and 00 REVISION values before alphabets. And I expect the alphabets to be sorted first and later the numbers. This means 0 and 00 should be after alphabets. And all other sorting is correct except 0, 00.

I use the following sql query:

```
SELECT D.PRIO, D.REVISION, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(ORDER BY  PRIO, REVISION ) RN FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, LEFT(REVISION, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVISION+'z')-1)) 'PRIO',REVISION  FROM DOCUMENTS )D
ORDER BY D.PRIO,D.REVISION ;
```

The result to above query shows 0 and 00 before alphabets.

| PRIO | REVISION | RN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 00 | 2 |
| 0 | A | 3 |
| 0 | a | 4 |
| 0 | B | 5 |
| 0 | b | 6 |
| 0 | C | 7 |
| 0 | c | 8 |
| 0 | D | 9 |
| 0 | d | 10 |
| 0 | E | 11 |
| 0 | e | 12 |
| 0 | F | 13 |
| 0 | f | 14 |
| 0 | G | 15 |
| 0 | g | 16 |
| 0 | H | 17 |
| 0 | h | 18 |
| 0 | I | 19 |
| 0 | i | 20 |
| 0 | J | 21 |
| 0 | K | 22 |
| 0 | L | 23 |
| 0 | M | 24 |
| 0 | P | 25 |
| 0 | R | 26 |
| 0 | S | 27 |
| 0 | SU | 28 |
| 0 | X | 29 |
| 0 | XX | 30 |
| 0 | Y | 31 |
| 1 | 01 | 32 |
| 1 | 1 | 33 |
| 1 | 1A | 34 |
| 2 | 02 | 35 |
| 2 | 2 | 36 |
| 2 | 2. | 37 |
| 3 | 03 | 38 |
| 3 | 3 | 39 |
| 4 | 04 | 40 |
| 4 | 4 | 41 |
| 5 | 05 | 42 |
| 5 | 5 | 43 |
| 6 | 06 | 44 |
| 6 | 6 | 45 |
| 7 | 07 | 46 |
| 7 | 7 | 47 |
| 8 | 08 | 48 |
| 8 | 8 | 49 |
| 9 | 09 | 50 |
| 9 | 9 | 51 |
| 10 | 10 | 52 |
| 11 | 11 | 53 |
| 12 | 12 | 54 |
| 13 | 13 | 55 |

Comment: Your question is explicitly saying the `1` is sorted correctly but `0` is not.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use `TRY_CONVERT` with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,REVISION) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         REVISION
```

This will order values that fail to convert first, which would be your alpha(numerical) values, and then the ones that can be. Then, in those groups, it would order them alphabetically, meaning `'AB'` before `'CD'`, and `'12'` before `'2'`.

If you want the numerical values to be ordered numerical, I would personally suggest you fix your design, and store the numerical values separate to the alpha ones. If you "can't", then you'll need separate clauses:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,REVISION) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,REVISION) IS NULL THEN REVISION END,
         TRY_CONVERT(int,REVISION)
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to make the logic change to the calculation for `rn`.  Then use `rn` for the ordering:

```
SELECT D.PRIO, D.REVISION,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRIO, (CASE WHEN REVISION IN ('0', '00') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) DESC, REVISION ) AS RN
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, LEFT(REVISION, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVISION+'z')-1)) as PRIO,
             REVISION 
      FROM DOCUMENTS
     ) D
ORDER BY RN
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This works, just I need to correct syntax: (CASE WHEN REVISION IN ('0', '00') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END).